# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta absoluta de un fichero referente a un content provider?

Tags: java, android, android-jellybean

Obtengo un archivo usando el Selector de archivo nativo de Android `filechooser`

```
Button myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_file);
if (myButton2 != null) {
    myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: btn_select_file");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); 
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File"), 2);

        }
    });
}
```

En versiones superiores a `JELLY-BEAN` me devuelve un `uri` que empieza con `content://com.android.providers...`

```
private String getDisplayNameFromUri(Uri uri) {
    String displayName = "";

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
        displayName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    } else if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            cursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        try {
            // moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor has 0 rows.
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    return displayName;
}
```

Para el tamaño algo parecido, modificando `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` para `OpenableColumns.SIZE`

Para obtener la fecha de modificación del ficher en `KITKAT`

```
String swap = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED));
```

Pero para versión `JELLY_BEAN` no encuentro nada y con:

```
File file = new File(uri.toString());

if (file.exists()) {
    Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
    Log.d(TAG, "lastModified: " + lastModified);
} else {
    Log.w(TAG, "No exist file: " + file);
}
```

Siempre me indica que el fichero no existe

> uri.toString() =>
>   content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2303

y si en el selector de archivos uso la APP Amaze (que es una app gestora de archivos) me devuelve

> file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/google-play-badge.png

Que no hay problema con el código de obtener la fecha de modificación.

Estoy mirando si hay alguna función para convertir la Uri del content provider a la ruta absoluta del documento, o cómo lo podría solventar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado una solución por [SO get real path from uri android kitkat new storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework) y he adaptado a mis sugerencias, ya que a veces si con el `filechooser` se usaba otro app de gestor de archivos, con el método original, devolvía null.

```
public static String getRealPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
        return uri.toString();

    } else if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        // DocumentProvider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];

                    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    }

                    // TODO handle non-primary volumes
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];

                    Uri contentUri = null;
                    if ("image".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }

                    final String selection = "_id=?";
                    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                            split[1]
                    };

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}


public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

**Su uso**

En el Retorno del filechooser

```
Log.d(TAG, "Ruta absoluta" + getRealPath(getBaseContext(), uri);
```

**Resultado**

> **Content provider:**
> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2303
>
> **Ruta absoluta:** file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/google-play-badge.png

También lo dejo alojado en un [Gist](https://gist.github.com/webserveis/409d927cc636a3985e3b731e43426ce5)